# What would be the base case of recursive function that should find sum of numbers in a string

Tags: c, recursion, integer, data-extraction, function-definition

For example, **int num(char [100])** is a function that finds sum of numbers in a string.

E.g. "123omaewamou7" should return *130*.

I tried to do it iteratively, and it seems that I had a handle on it. But I also got curious how one would do it recursively. Though I did not even come up with a base case for recursive function.

My first assumption is that I shall check every character of string as I did in iterative case.

What hint could you give to find the base case?

Comment: The base case is when there's nothing left to sum, so a string without numbers, no?

Comment: @MOehm so when character encounters non-digit one then I shall return the found number and if not then I just return sum?

Comment: No. When there are no numbers in the string, return zero. Otherwise, return the value of the first number plus the string sum of the string after that number.

Comment: https://ideone.com/wQNR07

Answer (score 0):

You could check the string left, I mean, if there are just numbers you are in the base case and you just return that number.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize sscanf. I believe loop would be better, but here's recursive version.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculateSum(char *string, int sum) {
    if (*string == '\0') return sum;

    int len = 0;
    int value = 0;

    if (sscanf(string, "%d%n", &value, &len) == 1) {
        sum += value;
    } else {
        len = 1;
    }

    string += len;

    return calculateSum(string, sum);
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", calculateSum("123omaewamou7", 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The base case of the recursive function is the condition `*s == '\0'` where `s` is the string passed to the function. That is when the terminating zero of the string is encountered.

It is enough to declare only one parameter of the function of the type `const char *`. And the return type should be `long long int`. This reduces the risk of overflow.

The function can be based on using the standard C function `strtoll`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

long long int sum( const char *s )
{
    long long int value = 0;

    if ( *s )
    {
        if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) || *s == '+' || *s == '-' )
        {
            char *p;

            value = ( strtoll( s, &p, 10 ) );

            s = p;
        }
        else
        {
            ++s;
        }

        value += sum( s );
    }

    return value;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "123omaewamou7";

    printf( "sum = %lld\n", sum( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sum = 130
```

You can exclude using the standard C function `isdigit` (and correspondingly the header `<ctype.h>`) the following way

```
long long int sum( const char *s )
{
    long long int value = 0;

    if ( *s )
    {
        if ( ( '0' <= *s && *s <= '9' ) || *s == '+' || *s == '-' )
        {
            char *p;

            value = ( strtoll( s, &p, 10 ) );

            s = p;
        }
        else
        {
            ++s;
        }

        value += sum( s );
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: _It is enough to declare only one parameter_: The code is cleaner, but in this way the compiler can not optimize using tail recursion.